# Is there a more pythonic way to skip rows in xlsx?

Tags: python, excel, csv, openpyxl

What I want to do: 
Skip A1: A6, Skip B1:B6 and save the rest to csv. Equivalently, I want to save `A7: B+ws.max_row` to csv.

My approach:

```
for sheet_name in wb.get_sheet_names():
    sheet = wb.get_sheet_by_name(sheet_name)

    col1 = []
    cnt = 1
    for i in sheet['A']:
        if cnt <= 6:
            cnt += 1
            continue
        col1.append(i.value)

    col2 = []
    cnt = 1
    for i in sheet['B']:
        if cnt <= 6:
            cnt += 1
            continue
        col2.append(i.value)

    data = zip(col1, col2)

    with open(str(sheet_name)+'.csv','wb') as out:
        csv_out=csv.writer(out)
        for row in data:
            csv_out.writerow(row)
```

What I don't like about my approach: `cnt` and manually choose A then choose B. (I want to skip the exact same number of rows for A and B)

My question:
Is there a more pythonic way to skip rows in xlsx?

Comment: Couldn't you `zip(sheet['A'], sheet['B'])` or possibly `for row in sheet['A:B']` (I'm not familiar with this package, so this is just guesswork on my part)

Comment: I tried `zip(sheet['A7': 'the_max_row'], sheet['B7': 'the_max_row'])` but it only returns tuple of cells but it cannot return the value of cells.

Comment: If you can get a tuple of cells, can't you work with the cells in each tuple?

Comment: looks like I have this package installed, I can try to test something quickly...

Comment: I tried to work with cells in each tuple. It makes me writing a double loop to get out the values. This approach is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

openpyxl 2.4 introduced the `iter_cols()` method for worksheets (NB. it is not available for read-only worksheets) so that you can simply do something like

```
cols = {1:[], 2:[]}

for idx, col in enumerate(ws.iter_cols(min_col=1, max_col=2, min_row=6), start=1):
    cols[idx] = [cell.value for cell in col]
```

Note, please do not use `wb.get_sheet_names()` and `wb.get_sheet_by_name()` as these methods have been deprecated. Use `wb.sheetnames` and `wb[sheetname]` instead.

Answer (score 3):

To me, the simplest thing to do would be to simply start at the 7th row and iterate row by row, writing each row to the CSV right then and there, NOT using a temporary copy. I don't know OpenPyXL very well. With [xlrd](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/xlrd), your entire code sample (everything you included in your question) would be expressed as

```
for sheet_name in wb.sheet_names():
    sheet = wb.sheet_by_name(sheet_name)

    with open(sheet_name + '.csv', 'wb') as out:
        csv_out = csv.writer(out)
        for rx in range(6, sheet.nrows):
            csv_out.writerow(sheet.row_values(rx, 0, 2))
```

(In that last line, you can omit the last two arguments to `row_values()` if your entire row consists of just those two columns. Those last two arguments work like the start and stop indices in a range or slice, with the start being *inclusive* and the stop being *exclusive*.)

If you really need your data stored in a temporary copy, xlrd lets you conveniently access a column of cells at a time:

```
data = zip(sheet.col_values(0, 6), sheet.col_values(1, 6))
```

The first argument for `col_values()` is the column index and the second argument is the starting row index. (If you needed to stop before the end, you would provide a third argument for the stop row index, just as I did for `row_values()` above.)